# Ruby on rails with postgresql: permission denied to create database

Tags: linux, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I trying to create db for my app. 
with command:

---

$bundle exec rake db:create (and i also try $rake db:create).

---

but i received:

```
PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied to create database
: CREATE DATABASE "list_development" ENCODING = 'unicode'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"list_development"}
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied to create database
: CREATE DATABASE "list_development" ENCODING = 'unicode'
```

How can i fix it? If i use sql3 - it's all fine. P.S. And yes, i created new superuser for postgresql.

Comment: Is your super user listed as the user in database.yml?

Comment: I checked it out and in .yml user is list (list is my app name) not root user.

Comment: The user there needs to have create privs. You can always create the database using the root user outside of rails. Then migrate as normal assuming your grant the list user permissions.

Comment: It's not normal, how can i fix it in global? I can't create users for all my apps.

Comment: It is 100% normal. Postgres has a permissions system that you would expect to find in an industrial strength RDBMS, unlike sqllite's permission system, which do I have write permission to the file.  In development I have a local postgres user that is a super user, and just use that user for all of my apps. This way it can create / remove databases, tables, etc.. For production each app runs with a user that has just enough permissions to do what it needs.  If this is dev I would just have rails use a root account.